# How SHA1 key for android studio can be same for multiple users?

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1

I was working with my team, everybody was using his/her laptop and android studio

while creating the SHA1 key everyone gets exactly the same SHA1 key, how can this be possible?

SHA1 key depends on default debug.keystore file

How this key can be exactly the same for all team members working on different PC's

Everyone followed this on their own PC.

[image]

Comment: There is no problem with having the same debug key. It even makes it easer to update with an apk build on another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It can be same for all the team members. You need to create your own keystore file. Use your created keystore as destination rather than debug keystore. Share same keystore with your team members, all will get same SHA1 key by using same key store.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 is a hash function.

You hash same file, you get same result.

It's part of the feature.